# How to use Asterisk AGI with python3?

Tags: python-3.x, asterisk, agi

Using  Asterisk 16.2.1 my `AGI` script (at the bottom) works with python2 `#!/usr/bin/env python2`, but not with python3 `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.

I do not even get as far as `agi.verbose("python agi started")` (with python3), so I assume it has something to do with the AGI import or initialization `agi = AGI()`

Having used `agi set debug on` does not really help, the only info I see is

```
Launched AGI Script /home/.../asteriskAgi.py
    -- <SIP/..-00000002>AGI Script /home/.../asteriskAgi.py completed, returning 0
```

As it works with python2, but not 3 I have also installed `pyst3` from https://pypi.org/project/pyst3/ , but it did not help (it does not work with or without `pyst3` installed).

**Q:** Any idea how to configure `asterisk` for python3, or how to find the root cause?
Any chance to get more detailed log information of where the script actually fails_

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import rpyc

from asterisk.agi import AGI

agi = AGI()
agi.verbose("python agi started")
aCallerId = agi.env['agi_callerid']
aType = agi.env["agi_type"]
agi.verbose("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX call from %s" % aCallerId)
agi.verbose(sys.executable)

l = [aCallerId, aType]
agi.verbose("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX l")

c = rpyc.connect("localhost", 18861)
c.root.asteriskCall(l)
```

---

Even this minimalistic version does not work with "3"

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import rpyc

from asterisk.agi import AGI

agi = AGI()
agi.verbose("python agi started")
```

---

eventually solved by:

1. uninstalled `pyst3` and
2. forced a re-install of `pyst2` like `pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall pyst2`. No idea what went wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your minimalistic version works for me(with pyst2 installed via pip)

Check permission and installed packages. Also ensure that your asterisk running under environment which able find python3 and packages installed.

Comment: After your post I have done 2 things: 1) uninstalled `pyst3` and forced a re-install of `pyst2` like `pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall pyst2`. No idea what went wrong in the first place.